# Are security updates phased too?

Tags: nvidia, updates, security

I just noticed today that some Nvidia-related updates were being [phased](https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/phased-updates.html).

The thing is, these are security updates.

Until now, I was thinking security updates would never be phased, for… well, security reasons : the updates have to be delivered everywhere as fast as possible.

Hence my question : is this a deliberate choice, or a bug ?

**EDIT :** I consider these updates as security updates because they’re published in lunar-security. The `update-manager` GUI shows them under *Security* too, which is the reason why I noticed this in the first place.

That being said, they’re published in lunar-updates too, which may be the reason why phasing applies.

Comment: I wonder if this is due to a kernel update in `-security`, which in turn may have required a rebuild of the driver packages that don't use DKMS (and since these are all built from the same source package, the non-DKMS ones got rebuilt as well, maybe?)

Comment: None of the phasing updates have a CVE listed in their changelogs. I concur with @muru: This looks like a case of packages *related to* a security update, but not themselves vulnerable.

Comment: @muru : Indeed, there has been a kernel update in `-security` at the same time. I had it installed, but at the same time the nvidia driver updates were deferred because of phasing, so I have the old driver and the new kernel. Strange… Seems to work though !

Comment: @user535733 : Yes, fortunately it likely doesn’t correct a vulnerability. I wonder what the criteria are to exclude an update from phasing though… I thought being published in `-security` was enough, but there must be something else

Comment: Try this: CVE --> Security Team workflow --> Immediate. No CVE --> Other Team workflow --> May be eligible for phasing.